# Capturar WebException en petición Asíncrona

Tags: c#, excepciones

Estoy haciendo peticiones asíncronas y las voy almacenando en un lista `Task`, al final de la iteración es decir ya que manda todas las peticiones utilizo el método `WhenAll().Result` para capturar todas las respuestas una vez que las peticiones hayan concluido y guardarlas en un arreglo, como se muestra en el siguiente código:

```
try
{
   IEnumerable<Task<string>> task = requestArray.Select((a, i) =>
   {
       var fareIds = new List<string>();
       var ticketsId = new List<string>();
       var seatsNumber = new List<string>();

       for (var posSeat = 0; posSeat < requestArray[i].seats.Length; posSeat++)
       {
           fareIds.Add(requestArray[i].seats[posSeat].fareId.ToString());
           ticketsId.Add(requestArray[i].seats[posSeat].ticketId.ToString());
           seatsNumber.Add(requestArray[i].seats[posSeat].number.ToString());
        }

        var xml = BlockSeatRQ(i, seatsNumber.ToArray(), fareIds.ToArray(), ticketsId.ToArray(), tokenRQ);

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        return Task.Run(() => client.UploadStringTaskAsync(Config.Endpoint + SEAT_BLOCK_URL, "POST", xml));
   });

   blockSeatResponses = Task.WhenAll(task).Result;       
}
catch (WebException e)
{


}
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando surgue una excepcion no entra al catch, si no que truena al momento de llamar el metodo `WhenAll` como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora la pregunta es, ¿Por que no entra al catch? y ¿Como le puedo hacer para que entre al catch?, ya que el servicio que estoy usando no me regresa un error concreto para usar simplemente `Exception` y con `WebException` me permite entrar al `Body` y sacar el mensaje de error.

Espero se entienda el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entra al `catch` porque estás atrapando solo excepciones del tipo `WebException`y en ese caso que marcas en tu imagen está lanzando una del tipo `AggregateException`. Hasta aquí el motivo.

Si quieres tratar tus excepciones específicamente debes apilar catchs con cada tipo y su tratamiento exclusivo, siempre es buena práctica  al final de todos los catchs atrapar las del tipo `Exception` así tu aplicación no lanzaría un error de excepción no controlada.

Un ejemplo:

```
try
{ 
    //...aquí algún código que probablemente lanze excepción
}
catch(WebException we)
{
    //aquí trato las excepciones del tipo WebException
}
catch(AggregateException ae)
{
    //aquí trato las excepciones AggregateException
    //en tu caso entraría a este catch
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //aquí trato las excepciones que no ingresaron en
    //los otros catch
}
```

---

**EDITADO:**

Para evitar la `AggregateException` puedes utilizar :

```
blockSeatResponses = await Task.WhenAll(task);
```

`await` devuelve el `result` del `task` y desenvuelve (unwrap) la `AggregateException`.

Comment: Me parece bien tu comentario, pero lo que pasa es que quiero que entre al `catch` de `webException` para sacar el `body` ya que en la `Exception` me regresa un error muy general

Comment: Hola @JoséGregorioCalderón, te endiendo, pero  o va a entrar de todas maneras, no es como funciona el try-catch, son excepciones de tipos distintos por lo tanto no va a llegar por ese catch, salvo que re lances tu excepción con un `throw new WebException`pero de todas maneras tendrías que atraparla con el `catch (AggregateException)` o `catch(Exception)`

Comment: @JoséGregorioCalderón Ahora edito la respuesta con alguna posible solución.